# Apps won´t start after upgrading to Android Studio 0.5.0

Tags: android, android-activity, securityexception

My apps don´t start anymore with adb after upgrading android studio.

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.myapp/com.android.myapp.application.ApplicationActivity } from null (pid=11313, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10274
>   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
>   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
>   at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2150)
>   at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:680)
>   at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:270)
>   at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
>   at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
>   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
>   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:243)
>   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

How can I solve it?

Edit:

There needs to be definately a problem with my project, which now matters under the new version of android studio and didn´t before. I´ve just started another project which works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"></uses-feature>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="com.dsi.ant.permission.ANT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.dsi.ant.permission.ANT_ADMIN" />

<application
    android:name="com.android.myapp.application.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver android:name="com.android.myapp.expansiondownloader.SampleAlarmReceiver"/>

    <activity android:name="com.android.myapp.expansiondownloader.SampleDownloaderActivity"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.android.myapp.expansiondownloader.DownloaderActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"></activity>

    <activity
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:name="com.android.appname.MainActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name="com.android.myapp.updater.UpdaterActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.android.myapp.functionality.music.export.filechooser.FileChooser"></activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.android.myapp.updater.notification.NotificationDeleteReceiver"></receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.android.myapp.functionality.mail.InternetConnectionReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.android.myapp.functionality.music.export.filechooser.SDCardStateChangedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_REMOVED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_EJECT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BAD_REMOVAL"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Now I did the following:

I´ve excluded the modul which didn´t work from the project, then I´ve replaced the content of the project (all subfolders and files) with the content of a working project.

Now I get:

> DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.android.appname/com.android.android.application.ApplicationActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
>   Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.android.appname/com.android.android.application.ApplicationActivity }
>   Error type 3
>   Error: Activity class {com.android.appname/com.android.android.application.ApplicationActivity} does not exist.

Both manifest files are completely equal

Attempt 2:

Now I copied the complete working module and imported it. AS named it to "MyModul2". Started and,...the same error.

What the hell is going on here?

Comment: Did you try to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Please post your manifest.

Comment: I have nothing changed on my manifests, they are all right. I´ll make a clean and build and try again

Comment: it still does not work. the apps itself are startable if I start them directly on the device, but adb seems to have no rights to start them remotely

Comment: AS 0.5.0 introduced new gradle and build tools. Did you try editting your build.gradle to use these new tool and gradle?

Comment: I think I don´t even use gradle as my projects came from eclipse. I have gradle stuff in my library project, but this seems to be not used, as I only start the other projects. They have no gradle files at all

Comment: hmm just updated my AS and my AVDs stopped working -.-.... Did you try updating your sdk?

Comment: This was also my first thought, but didn´t help

Comment: as @CommonsWare said, could you please post your manifest?

Comment: Did this run on earlier versions of AS, or did you go from eclipse directly to AS?

Comment: until the update everything ran fine

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have something in your IDE set up to run a particular activity (`com.android.myapp.application.ApplicationActivity`) when you run the project. However, this activity does not exist in your manifest. I would have expected a different error message, though.

> I think I don´t even use gradle as my projects came from eclipse

All Android Studio builds go through Gradle.

Comment: I have copied a working module into the module which doesn´t work. Still the same. Now my guess is, there is something wrong inside the .idea folder

Comment: @Nachbar90: You could try deleting (or moving to a temporary spot) your `.iml` file and restarting Android Studio. It will be rebuilt from your `build.gradle` file and may clear up some issues. I haven't messed with `.idea/` yet, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Now I deleted everything and checked it out again and now it works fine